# How to return true in unit tests for Arrays.asList().contains()

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a if check in my method.

```
if(Arrays.asList(myStringArray).contains(myString)) {
  doXYZ();
}
```

How do I mock this line in unit tests so that I can return true or false.
I want to do something like.
when(Arrays.asList(myStringArray).contains(myString)).thenReturn(true)
But that does not work.

Comment: Make `myStringArray` so that it contains `myString`?

Comment: You could mock a static method, but without more context it is difficult to say if it is a good advice. Can you contol the contents of the array from your test? See https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.6/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mock static methods with Mockito.  You have to either 1) update your code to do it differently or 2) use something different e.g. [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: You can, since 3.4.0